# Do I need transit visa for Amsterdam Airport?

Tags: schengen, paperwork, transit-visas, bulgaria

I am Palestinian with a Lebanese travel document, travelling from India to Bulgaria. I have a visit visa for Bulgaria and the layover in Amsterdam is 5 hours.

Do I need a transit visa?

Comment: Is it a Lebanese passport? If not, what is the travel document called?

Comment: No, it is Lebanese travel document issued for Palestinian refugees in Lebanon.

Answer (score 2):

If you are travelling on a single ticket, then no, you shouldn't need a transit visa.

While I have doubt about the general situation of a Palestinian with a Lebanese travel document:

- The [official site](https://www.netherlandsandyou.nl/travel-and-residence/visas-for-the-netherlands/airport-transit-visa) tells us that "You **only** need an airport transit visa if your nationality appears on the list of countries whose nationals require a visa (PDF, 69 KB)" and the list does neither contain Palestine nor Lebanon,
- Multiple third-party web sites tell us that "Holders of a travel document for Palestinian stateless/refugees which has been issued by Egypt, Lebanon or Syria need an airport transit visa ((A 1951 Convention travel document/ A 1954 Convention travel document)."

there is an exemption that is the same on all sites and applies to you:

> If your nationality appears on this list, check whether you have an exemption. An airport transit visa is also **not required** if you: ... **have a visa** or residence permit **for a country in** the Schengen Area, **the EU** or the EEA

Since Bulgaria is part of the EU, your Bulgarian visa should suffice.

Comment: Am holding a travel document for Palestinians issued by Lebanon, but i have a valid visit visa to Bulgaria